# What Does A "There is a user sharing this computer..." Window Mean?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, user-account

I was trying to turn off my Macbook Pro and suddenly got this message. As far as I know, there's no reason why this should be happening. Anyone want to fill me in on some possibilities?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, you've enabled File Sharing in the Sharing section of System Preferences. Someone on your network has connected to your computer, either as a registered user or as a guest.

Unless this kind of access is absolutely required, it's good security practice to disable both File Sharing and the Guest user in System Preferences -> Sharing and System Preferences -> Accounts and Groups, respectively.

Comment: For Lion, it was in "Users & Groups" under "System" and "Sharing" under "Internet & Wireless" in the System Preferences. Thanks though. It's much appreciated.